# Mocking logout throws an error

Tags: java, testing, cookies, mockito, logout

Hi i have the below two methods one for logging out and the other is internally called to clear cookies. I first started with mocking the second method to delete cookie. I referred this code from DZone.

I edited the code of my test method. It is working fine but i am unable to get the solution for Logout method

```
public class Service
{
    @RequestMapping(value = "/logout", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String logout(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
    session.setAttribute("sessionid","id");
    Cookie first=new Cookie("name","Mycookie");
    response.addCookie(first);
        if (request.isRequestedSessionIdValid() && session != null) {
        session.invalidate();
        }
        HttpServletResponse sessionRes=handle(request,response);
    return "You have successfully logged out";
        }


    public HttpServletResponse handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    {
        Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
        if(cookies!=null || cookies.length!=0)
        {
            for(Cookie cookie:cookies)
            {
                cookie.setMaxAge(0);
                cookie.setValue(null);
                cookie.setPath("/");
                response.addCookie(cookie);
            }
            response.addHeader("message", "No cookies found");
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

Handling logout works fine as below but unable to work on testing logout method, it throws me null pointer

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class LogoutTest {
    @InjectMocks
    Service service;

    @Mock
    Cookie cookie;
    @Mock
    HttpServletRequest request;
    @Mock
    HttpServletResponse response;

    @Test
    public void TestHandle()
    {
        Cookie[] cookieArr = {cookie};
    response.addCookie(cookieArr[0]);
    when(request.getCookies()).thenReturn(cookieArr);
    service.handle(request, response);
   // verify(response).addCookie((Cookie) any());
    verify(response).addHeader("message", "No cookies found");
   Assert.assertEquals(cookie.getValue(),null);
    }

}
```

here is my test method for Logout and it throws me weird exception. I don't know where I went wrong. I called the handle method too.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class LogoutTest {
    @InjectMocks
    Service service;

    @Mock
    Cookie cookie=new Cookie("fname","ram");
    @Mock
    HttpServletRequest request;
    @Mock
    HttpServletResponse response;
    @Mock
    HttpSession session;

    @Test
    public void TestLogout()
    {

    session=request.getSession();
    request.setAttribute("sid", "id");
    Cookie[] cookieArr = {cookie};
    response.addCookie(cookieArr[0]);
    when(request.getCookies()).thenReturn(cookieArr);

    when(service.handle(request, response)).thenReturn(response);
     Assert.assertEquals("You have successfully logged out",service.logout(request, response));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing mocking wrong, using

```
when(service.handle(request,response)).thenReturn(response);
```

Means, that `service` is mocked, and when `handle` method is called from this case, return `response`, so you are not testing `handle` method at all.

```
@Test
public void test_handle() {
    Cookie[] cookieArr = {new Cookie("fname","ram")};
    when(request.getCookies()).thenReturn(cookieArr);
    service.handle(request, response);
    verify(response).addCookie(any());
    verify(response).addHeader("message", "No cookies found");
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thank You, I tried the same before but i was getting OnGoingStubbing error so i changed to this. I get the error as the method thenReturn (Cookie[]) in the type OngoingStubbing<Cookie[]> is not applicable for arguments (Cookie)

Comment: Thank You, it worked finally. Just that i had to cast any() to Cookie. Thank You sooo much. I was stuck in the same from a day. I will start wring test for logout too. can you give me a hint kind on what i should exactly write in when method

Comment: @Rvmems there are a lot of weird logic in your code, but to test logout method, you need to test handle method again, since handle is always called, and cannot be mocked there...

Comment: So do you mean its not possible to write test for logout mehtod

Comment: It is, but it will envelop the test case for handle method, that is what I am saying...

Comment: I added the test method of logout too. I am not getting where i am wrong. It gives me exception in the call to Handle method. org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.CannotStubVoidMethodWithReturnValue: 
'addHeader' is a *void method* and it *cannot* be stubbed with a *return value*!